# How to put an if statment depending on the gender of the user in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, if-statement

How to put an if statment depending on the gender of the user in mysql query?

I want to change the $avatar  image depending on the gender.

if it's male I store this image --> avatar/male.png

if it's female I store this image --> avatar/female.png

here is mysql query

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `etudiants`
    (id_etudiant, id_filiere, dateInscription, anneeScolaire, classe, typeFormation, filiere, nomPrenom, CIN, niveauScolaire, dateNaissance, sexe, nationalite, adresse, ville, tel, npPere, telPere, formPere, npMere, telMere, formMere, avatar)
        VALUES
    ('','$id_filiere','$date','$anneeScolaire', '$classe', '$typeFormation', '$filiere', '$nomPrenom','$CIN', '$niveauScolaire', '$dateNaissance', '$sexe','$nationalite', '$adresse','$ville','$tel','$npPere','$telPere','$formPere','$npMere','$telMere','$formMere','$avatar');
    ") or die (mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE WHEN` or `CONCAT`.

Replace `'$avatar'` in the query you provided with this code and it should work:

```
CASE sexe WHEN 'male' THEN 'avatar/male.png' ELSE 'avatar/female.png' END
```

Or even this:

```
CONCAT('avatar/', sexe, '.png')
```